# Add WebDriverManager to Katalon studio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, katalon-studio, webdriver-manager

**How do I add Selenium WebDriverManager dependency to Katalon studio build.gradle?**

I am unable to build the build.gradle file as under command prompt it gradle katalonCopyDependencies does not work

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No errors or anything, I installed WebDriverManager jar files but again it did not work, as Katalon uses its internal driver executable files.